# How to extract an array of values from a single DataRow element?

Tags: c#, arrays, postgresql, datarow

I am having trouble searching for this because the term array gives me a million unrelated results focusing on converting an entire `DataRow` into an array.  Here's some simple code for an example. `drUser` is a `DataRow` object.

```
User dcUser = new User();

dcUser.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(drUser["user_id"].ToString());
```

That gives me an integer value no problem.  But I've got an array of values inside another element, e.g. {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. When I try to do something similar like this:

```
dcUser.SystemIDs = drUser["system_ids"].ToString();
```

It gives me the type of that array of values (`System.Int32[]`) instead of all the actual values. It doesn't even tell me the number of elements in that result.  I was thinking I could do something like:

```
dcUser.SystemIDs = drUser["system_ids"][0].ToString();
```

Basically create a loop to iterate and get each value, but that syntax is no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the values out with this code:

```
User dcUser = new User();
int[] anSystemIDs = (int[])drUser["system_ids"];
string strSystemIDs = "";
dcUser.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(drUser["user_id"].ToString());
for (int i = 0; i < anSystemIDs.Length ; i++)
{
    strSystemIDs += anSystemIDs[i].ToString() + ", ";
}
dcUser.SystemIDs = strSystemIDs.Substring(0, strSystemIDs.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ syntax to build a string, assuming you WANT a string to be in SystemIDs. Since `drUser["system_ids"]` returns an `int[]`, we can use:

```
 string res = "";
 drUser["system_ids"].ToList().ForEach((int i) => res += i + " ");
```

Maybe there's an even better way without having to create the temporary variable first and directly returning the result.
If you don't want this to be a space-seperated string, why not let SystemIDs be an `int[]` and store `drUsers["system_ids"]` in it directly?

Comment: This wasn't the answer, but it had enough hints to help me figure it out, so +1. And for your question: the code is already using a comma-delimited string for these values in a lot of other places.